# Memory issue on creating dynamic view inside RecyclerView

Tags: android

I am creating UI layout dynamically inside the `RecyclerView` which causes out of memory issue when the application is used for long time.Ui being re created on scrolling up and down. How can i prevent the creation of views on scrolling? my code looks as follows.

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) getBaseView().findViewById(R.id.container);
        container.removeAllViews();
        int position = 0;

        for (int i= 0; i<content.size()/2;i ++) {
            LinearLayout ln = new LinearLayout(getBaseView().getContext());
            ln.setWeightSum(2);
            ln.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            for (int j = 0; j<COLUMN_COUNT; j++) {
                VIOPlayListItemView tile = new VIOPlayListItemView(getBaseView().getContext());

                tile.setTag(position);
                tile.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                ln.addView(tile);

                if (position <content.size()) {
                    tile.setData(content.get(position));
                }
                position ++;
            }

            container.addView(ln);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i don't now why that happened if Your code above not in scroll listener or other same. You only create and add all view one time in other event (exp: onCreateView or somthing similar)

Comment: i understood your problem but i am unable to figure out the exact line where the problem is occurring. Please add some more code it will help understanding the problem better.

Comment: You can inflate the Layout instead of getting baseView

Comment: This code is inside the viewholder which will be executed on onBindViewHolder

Comment: I am creating these views inside the vieholder